# C# Array slice without copy

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, slice, space-efficiency

I'd like to pass a sub-set of a C# array to into a method. I don't care if the method overwrites the data so would like to avoid creating a copy.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in ArraySlice<T>: https://github.com/henon/SliceAndDice

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the method to take an `IEnumerable<T>` or `ArraySegment<T>`.

You can then pass `new ArraySegment<T>(array, 5, 2)`

Comment: You may add an example of `IEnumerable<T>` with `Skip` / `Take`.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: `ArraySegment<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: You do lose fast element access though when using ArraySegment, which implements IEnumerable, IList, both of which dont guarantee O(1) for accessing a random element, right?

Comment: @t: `ArraySegment<T>` is O(1).  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/arraysegment.cs#164

Answer (score 7):

With C# 7.2 we have `Span<T>` . You can use the extension method `AsSpan<T>` for your array and pass it to the method without copying the sliced part. eg:

```
Method( array.AsSpan().Slice(1,3) )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following class.  Note you may need to modify it depending on whether you want `endIndex` to be inclusive or exclusive.  You could also modify it to take a start and a count, rather than a start and an end index.

I intentionally didn't add mutable methods.  If you specifically *want* them, that's easy enough to add.  You may also want to implement `IList` if you add the mutable methods.

```
public class Subset<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private IList<T> source;
    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    public Subset(IList<T> source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            if (startIndex + i >= endIndex)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            return source[startIndex + i];
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return endIndex - startIndex; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return source.Skip(startIndex)
            .Take(endIndex - startIndex)
            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are immutable by size (i.e. you can't change size of a array), so you can only pass a subtracted copy of the original array.  As option you can pass two indexes aside original array into method and operate on the basis of additional two indexes..

Answer (score -4):

you can use Linq take funktion and take as many elements from array as you want

```
var yournewarray = youroldarray.Take(4).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you add `ToArray` to the end then you're performing a copy.  You'd also need to use both `Skip` and `Take` to get an arbitrary subset.  Finally, if he wants quick indexed access within the subset he wouldn't get it from an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: -1: OP specifically posted he does _not_ want a copy.